# open node-reference links title in popup

Tags: 7, nodes

I want in my node view pages, node reference links open in popup window or lightbox window.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a theme_preprocess() function to add attributes to that link, or you can create a custom field template that adds classes or specifies a target.

For a new window/tab, you'd add `target="_blank"` or if you want to use an overlay you would add classes as specified in the module that provides that functionality, such as [Lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) or [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox).